# Is there a simpler way to zip two .onReceive in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
@State private var showUpEmotion = false
@State private var showDownEmotion = false
```

When two pieces of data from an observableobject come online  some view is shown

```
HStack {
    if showUpEmotion && showDownEmotion
    {
          SomeViewIsShown()
    }
}
.onReceive(model.$meLike) { value in
                        withAnimation {
                            if value != nil {
                                showUpEmotion = true
                            } else {
                                showUpEmotion = false
                            }
                        }
}
.onReceive(model.$meDislike) { value in
                        withAnimation {
                            if value != nil {
                                showDownEmotion = true
                            } else {
                                showDownEmotion = false
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Is there a simpler/cleaner way to zip that data from ObservableObject ?
naturally withAnimation does not compile in the observableobject proper -> I have to use that inside the view :(

Comment: Do both `value` have the same type? Then move the whole body into a new function, say, `func toggleDownEmotion(_ value: MyType)`, and you can then do `.onReceive(model.$meLike, perform: toggleDownEmotion).onReceive(model.$meDisLike, perform: toggleDownEmotion)` (note the _missing_ argument `(…)` on `toggleDownEmotion`).

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. What are you trying to achieve? What's not working? What do you mean by _"zip that data from ObservableObject"_? Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, both values are the same type

Comment: @DarkDust when toggleDownEmotion the model meLike or meDisLike (depending which one it was called for) still has the old value. So sadly it does not help.

Comment: so I just zipped them at the source rather than destination as Ashley Mills have suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what you're trying to achieve, but possibly moving some of your `Bool`s into `struct`s would simplify?

```
struct ShowEmotions {
    var up = false
    var down = false

    var both: Bool {
        up && down
    }
}

struct Likes {
    var like = false
    var dislike = false
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var me = Likes()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showEmotions = ShowEmotions()
    @StateObject var model = Model()
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if showEmotions.both {
                SomeViewIsShown()
            }
        }
        .onReceive(model.$me) { me in
            withAnimation {
                showEmotions.up = me.like
                showEmotions.down = me.dislike
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you only need a single `onReceive`

Comment: That seems cleaner.